# Why did the AF Assist Beam on my Godox X1T-C stop working after a firmware update?

Tags: canon, wireless-triggers, godox

Recently I updated firmware of my Godox X1T-C remote trigger to be able to use it with Canon EOS400D which have trimmed down flashlight hotshoe (trigger pin is missing). Now the trigger is working and can be used with all kind of legacy flashlights (in manual mode only) but the assist beam is not showing up anymore. Does anybody experianced the same issue or does anybody know what may be the reason behind this?

Comment: What AF mode do you have selected in the camera's settings?

Comment: I had the same problem with a Nikon, turns out the light only works if the center AF point is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the AF mode from 'One Shot AF' to 'AI Servo AF', the assist beam will not operate with any flashes or triggers that have assiste beams, including Canon external flashes and even the popup flashes on Canon cameras that have them.

In order to use an AF assist light, the AF mode must be operating in 'One Shot AF' mode.

If you are using 'AI Focus AF', where the camera initially uses 'One Shot AF' but will switch to 'AI Servo AF' if it senses the subject distance has changed, then when the camera is initially in 'One Shot AF' mode the assist beam/light will operate until focus is locked, but if/when the camera switches to 'AI Servo AF' mode then the assist beam/light will no longer operate.

Comment: Nope, it's not that, I am always using One Shot AF mode. And just to be clear, I am refering to AF assist beam from Godox (not the camera).

Comment: If you want us to help you solve your issue, you need to give us more details about what settings you are using. Otherwise we're just taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: I've tried everything, every possible settings, including all focus poins, every function and custom functin on both camera, and commander (flash is fully manual). Assist beam on godox just stopped working after firmware upgrade. I will dissasemble it and test the assist beam switch, may be hardware failure...

Comment: It's definitly foulty hardware switch after all... It starts working after applying slight pressure to assist beam switch on commander while autofocusing. I will replace it tomorrow...